# POST request from localhost:3000 to AWS Lambda function not working because of CORS

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I have been breaking my head on the CORs issue for over two days now. I have looked at ALL possible solutions provided here on stackoverflow and also in the AWS documentation.

I have a client side server which sends a POST request to my Lambda function on AWS. I have enabled CORS in my AWS CDK code. See code snippet below:

```
    const apiGateway = new api_gw.LambdaRestApi(this, 'ingress-api', {
      handler: apiLambda,
      integrationOptions: {
        proxy: true,
        allowTestInvoke: true
      },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowOrigins: api_gw.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS, // or specify your own list of origins
        allowMethods: api_gw.Cors.ALL_METHODS, // or specify your own list of methods
        allowHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'X-Amz-Date', 'Authorization', 'X-Api-Key'], // customize allowed headers
      },
    });
```

In my Lambda function I also return as follows on the '/encode/' path ('https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/encode') :

```
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",  # Allows requests from any origin
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
        },
        "body": json.dumps(response)
    }
```

Using a simple `curl` I do see that I get the correct response back. But with the browser, I keep get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/encode' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have checked `curl` with the OPTIONS method and it does give me back:

> access-control-allow-origin: *
> access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key

I also tried sending the POST request from the JS on the client side as `Content-Type: 'text/plain'`. But that also does not work.

Again, I have, in as much capacity I have, looked at all possible solutions StackOverflow has to offer and I am posting after two days of banging my head.

Any suggestion, tips, etc. would just get me out of the rut right now.

Best wishes.

EDIT: I think I see why I get the CORS error but I don't understand it. I did a manual test of the POST method in my AWS console and I see that the return from my endpoint in the lambda function is included in the 'body' of the message. More precisely, my return is the following:

```
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",  # Allows requests from any origin
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
        },
        "body": json.dumps(response)
    }
```

So I expected to see the CORS headers in the response. But I do not see them. As a result the browser will block the request from the localhost server. In fact, the headers are included in the response body. Which is very strange because I have configured the Lambda function as a proxy integration so the API Gateway should return whatever the Lambda function endpoint is returning as 'statusCode', 'headers', 'body' etc. So I don't understand why it is not interpreting the return from the Lambda function as that and just interprets it as 'body'. See the image below for the response I see when I test the endpoint in the AWS console. The headers are put in the body of the response rather than being interpreted as real headers. The official AWS documentation on enabling CORS for proxy integrations also recommends exactly what I have implemented: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#apigateway-enable-cors-proxy

[image: response of testing method on aws console]

**UPDATE:** I finally managed to get it working by converting the API Gateway from REST API to HTTP API. The HTTP API allowed me to configure CORS in the AWS console and use a proxy Lambda integration. The only main thing to note is to NOT include the headers as  a part of the return from the Lambda function. I.e., suppose you have some dictionary 'response' that your Lambda function like to return, then just do `return response` and NOT ```
return {
"statusCode": 200,
"headers": {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",  # Allows requests from any origin
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
},
"body": json.dumps(response)
}

Comment: You say your `OPTIONS` response includes he correct headers. What about he actual `POST`? Seemingly it doesn't. And yeah, you might get the correct answer with curl, because curl is not a browser and doesn't care about CORS

Comment: have you checked what response headers the browser request receives?

Comment: "Perhaps you just have a syntax error and this is failing because of that" Valid point, but the error provided is definitely a CORS error.  A syntax error would show up in the developer tools just like the CORS error does.  "You say your OPTIONS response includes he correct headers. What about he actual POST" CORS decisions are made on the response from OPTIONS pre-flight headers, not the actual request's headers.

Comment: @Phil the script is in Python.

Comment: @derpirscher If I do curl with POST, I simply get back the expected result from my Lambda function (which is just a presigned s3 URL link). It looks all correct. I understand that the curl does not care about CORS and but it was a sanity check to make sure things are correctly received at the Lambda function. I am still getting the CORS error from the browser and there is no solution on SO or AWS docs that I have not implemented. Really at my wits end.

Comment: @erik258 as Erik mentions, there is no syntax error, just the CORS error and on the surface I have set everything correctly at the receiver Lambda server to handle CORS. But still get the error. Unfortunately I cannot even disable the cors, since I need to process the response from the Lambda server which is a presigned s3 URL link to which my client server will upload a file.

Comment: @erik258 Still, even if the OPTIONS request is successful, it will throw a CORS error if the response to the actual request doesn't contain CORS headers.

Comment: @derpirscher exactly! I am doing that since my Lambda is a proxy integration. I have updated my post to reflect that. But somehow the response or the return from the Lambda function is not parsed correctly and the entire response is just put in the BODY.

Comment: That sounds like the integration format used by API Gateway doesn't match the one the lambda expects.

Comment: @erik258 could you please explain in more details what the mismatch in integration format mean? I'd love to make some progress here. Thanks!